# How to access gmail messages under labels that aren't visible to IMAP?

Tags: android, api, gmail, gmail-imap

Gmail allows for disabling specific labels from showing via IMAP. However, the gmail android app can access all labels including those hidden from IMAP.

I'm developing an android email client and need to have similar access to messages under labels which are hidden from IMAP - how can I achieve this?

Comment: If google does this using some undocumented api, a great answer would be some instructions on how to tap into this api -- I don't mind if it's not guaranteed to remain the same for any period of time.

Answer (score 0):

IMAP command XLIST is supposed to return all lables.

By default, hiding the labels means hiding the folders on IMAP, not the labels themselves.

Comment: If a folder is hidden on IMAP, how can I search the messages inside it? How does the XLIST command help me? I already know the name of the folder which is hidden and which I invariably need to access ("All Mail").

Answer (score 0):

Google's gmail app doesn't appear to use IMAP as per this discussion:
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/hCB_NzodMts

This answer seems relevant:
[How can I manage Gmail labels using Google API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963429/how-can-i-manage-gmail-labels-using-google-api)